# Is Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor non-blocking?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

If I add a callback method to a ListenableFuture that returned from a method annotated with springs @Async annotation, will the thread taken from the threadpool used by @Async block until the call back is returned, or will the thread be returned to the threadpool to be reused until the callback is call?

I am **NOT** asking if the thread used by the controller is returned to the servlet. I am asking only about the thread from the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ListenableFutureAsyncController {

    @Autowired
    IHeavyLiftingService heavyLiftingService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    DeferredResult<String> home() {
        // Create DeferredResult
        final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();

        //Call to the async service
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = heavyLiftingService.heavyLifting();

        future.addCallback(
          new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
                result.setResult(response.getBody());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                result.setErrorResult(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // Return the thread to servlet container, 
        // the response will be processed by another thread.
        return result;
    }

}
```

Service that implements the @Async method

```
@Service
public class HeavyLiftingServiceImpl implements IHeavyLiftingService {

    @Async(value="asyncServiceThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ListenableFuture<String> heavyLifting() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The asyncServiceThreadPoolTaskExecutor is an instance of a org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Please provide links to documentation describing this behavior if possible.

Comment: Did u solve this? I'm with the same doubt.

Comment: Yes, the thread taken from the asyncServiceThreadPoolTaskExecutor will block until the heavyLifting method completes(The work has to be done somewhere right?) Once the work completes the thread is released back to the thread pool for use by another task. I may be able to give a more detailed answer if you tell me what you're trying to do.